# How to pass redux store between React native components? Keep getting Could not find "store" in either the context or props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-native

I am trying to solve a state management issue. I have 2 react native components. The react native component goes via native code/module to open the other component instead of going the react native route. 
 Code that starts another react component from the first component

```
reactView.startReactApplication(
                    reactInstance,
                    "Second Component",
                    null
            );
```

If I look at this it's recreating the underlying react context object again. The First component is properly loaded which obviously has the store configured on it i.e. in my AComponent.js

```
import data from '../../initialState'
const initialState = data
const store = storeFactory(initialState);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        intValue : state.intValue,
    }
}

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps)(AView)
const AComponent = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Container />
  </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AComponent', () => AComponent);
```

but when I try to access the store in the B component, it does not work and comes back with the error

> Could not find "store" in either the context or props of
>   "Connect(BComponent)"

The B component looks something like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        intValue : state.intValue
    }
}

const BContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(BView)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BContainer', () => BContainer);
```

My initialState.json file

```
{
    "intValue": 10
}
```

Comment: Can you post the file containing the store ?

Comment: Is this good enough or do you want me to add some more?